# How to access foreign key in a django template? (ListView)

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, python-3.x

In my project, the `Profile` model has `Foreign Key` relation with `Education` instance. Here are my models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    education = models.ForeignKey(Education, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="education")

class Education(models.Model):
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    edu_start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    edu_end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.degree)
```

Now, using the Django `ListView`, I am not being able to display the data of foreign key. My views:

```
class EducationView(CreateView):
    form_class = EducationForm
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    template_name = "profile_settings.html"

class EducationList(ListView):
    model = Profile
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'object'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    template_name = "profile_settings.html"
```

**Template**

```
{% for obj in profile.education.all %}
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2>{{ obj.degree }}</h2>
        <br>
        <div>
            {{ obj.school }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Education form saves data to the database but I couldn't fetch it using the template code.

Note: I'm using single template for CreateView and ListView.

Comment: I think you need to use `{% for obj in object_list.education.all %}` instead of `{% for obj in profile.education.all %}`

Comment: Tried it, not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ListView you specified context_object_name  as 'object'. So inside the template, the context is referred to an object.

So the code look like

```
{% for each_profile in object %}
    {% for obj in each_profile.education.all %}
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>{{ obj.degree }}</h2>
            <br>
            <div>
                {{ obj.school }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this:

```
{% for obj in object %}  <!-- as your context_object_name is `object` -->
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2>{{ obj.education.degree }}</h2>  <!-- accessed foreign key -->
        <br>
        <div>
            {{ obj.education.school }}  <!-- accessed foreign key -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

### Update

If you are using this template in create view then update the View like this:

```
class EducationView(CreateView):
    form_class = EducationForm
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    template_name = "profile_settings.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EducationView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['profiles'] = Profile.objects.all()  # I don't want to mix up `object` here. so using profiles
        return context
```

Now in ListView and template, we are going to update context object as well:

```
# view
class EducationList(ListView):
    model = Profile
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'profiles'
    template_name = "profile_settings.html"

# template

{% for obj in profiles %}
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2>{{ obj.degree }}</h2>
        <br>
        <div>
            {{ obj.school }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```